# Logitech MX5500 Keycounter

Tags: logitech-mouse, logitech-keyboard

I have the Logitech MX5500 Keyboard and Mouse. The keyboard has a LCD screen with some information. 
There is also a keycounter. And I was wondering, is there a way I can change the value of the keycounter?
A few days ago my batteries from the keyboard died, and when I changed them, the keycounter had been reset to 0. 
I want to know if there is a way to change it back to its old values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put on a good movie, and then sit through it spamming your keyboard to reach the value you want ;)

Now I know this might not be the answer you wish for, but it's possible that maybe you can't directly change the value of the key counter. The reason it was done so might be that, well, someone probably relies on that counter to tell the truth, not what someone else has written on it. Much like a car distance meter, perhaps.

Hope it works out for you, sorry for not having more than this.